# Best practice for <Include> file placement?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I'm migrating an apache configuration from a Red Hat machine to a Debian machine, and the source configuration uses  directives in its site configurations. Debian clearly has opinions about how configuration files should be structured; sites go in sites-available, mods go in mods-available, etc. So... where should files "Include"d by site files go? I could make an "include" subdirectory of `/etc/apache2`, and I think that's where I'm headed now, but that doesn't feel like I'm playing by the debian rules, exactly.

EDIT: I've now been and read README.Debian, and ... well, it seems to suggest the tactic of putting files in `conf-available` but being careful *not* to enable them with a2enconf, because then they'll be included by default at the global level. That scares me, and I'm frankly still inclined to make my own `include` directory, just to prevent an accidental a2enconf.

Opinions/Advice appreciated!

Comment: You can't avoid Debian? That's the first thing I would do. After considering Debian's opinions about how to structure the Apache (and lately nginx) configuration for the last couple of decades, I've come to the conclusion that they're so horribly wrong in so many ways that it's just best avoided entirely.

Comment: No, actually I'm a pretty big fan of Debian...

Comment: Really, your comments seem to be about the debian maintainers of apache; that seems like a relatively minor consideration in choosing an OS.

Comment: Oh, I could go on for days about technical things Debian does that I think are wrong, but as far as I can tell they mostly aren't relevant to your question.